# Waiting from input from form (VBA\MS Access)

Tags: forms, loops, ms-access

I have the following (pseudo-)code:

```
public publVar

Sub
    publVar = ""

    OpenForm Form1

    Do until publVar <> ""
        Sleep 100
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'Do Something with publVar
End Sub
```

It is supposed to stop the execution of the code until a value is assigned to publVar on Form1. There is the option to assign the attribute "Popup" to a form in Access to prevent code from being executed but that didnt work for me. 
My Question is: Is there a better way to do this in Access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [OpenForm Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx) includes a [WindowMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195725.aspx) argument. Use acDialog to halt execution until the form has closed.

This should free you of nearly all the code above.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what i was looking for. It might be a silly question but is it absolutely reliable if i need 100% consistency (execution must not continue before the scripts on the form finished)?

Comment: I have never hit a problem with acDialog yet where execution continued. It is annoying in quite different ways :)

Comment: And to return values back form that dialog form, this explains how to do this without using global vars and other messy approaches. http://www.kallal.ca/Dialog/Index.html

Comment: That looks like a very nice approach. Will try it. And I will also check the other articles on your page, seems very interesting :)

Comment: Martin, if you want Albert to get your note, use @ followed by his user name.

Comment: For a single return, I generally prefer to use the tag property of the form. If the form is updated, the tag property gets the value, if it is cancelled, the tag property is set to a suitable return. After the form is hidden, the tag property is returned to my calling module. It makes generic code easier.

Comment: @Remou That also sounds interesting, but in this case i need to prevent the user from clicking the X-Button or set up a suitable errorhandling... right?

Comment: Get rid of the X button. It is an option in form design.